# How to hide a tab in ext4.1?

Tags: extjs4.1

How can i hide the tab of a tabpanel dynamically ?

Iam using the method

```
        tabpanel.items.items[0].tab.setVisible(false);
```

But using the above method, it was destroying all the items in that tab.

How to make hide / visible that tab with all the previous items ?

Answer (score 0):

Configure your `tabpanel` with:

```
autoDestroy: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try autoDestroy: false on the tab item itself?

Comment: yes... But it was not working... It was destroying the items in the tab when iam closing the tab.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it works:

```
// get tab panel
var tabPanel = wnd.down('#myTabPanel');

if (showTab1) {
    tabPanel.down('#myTab1').show();
    tabPanel.down('#myTab2').hide();
} else {
    tabPanel.down('#myTab1').hide();
    tabPanel.down('#myTab2').show();
}
```